# Trying to make sense of npm audit results

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

**Background**

If I do `npm audit` on a ReactJS application we haven't touched in a year (until recently), I get the following summary:

```
found 356 vulnerabilities (321 low, 20 moderate, 14 high, 1 critical)
in 11345 scanned packages   run `npm audit fix` to fix 3 of them.  
353 vulnerabilities require semver-major dependency updates.
```

If I do that `npm audit fix` those 3 vulnerabilities are resolved, the others are not because they are breaking changes.

Doing another `npm audit` I get this summary:

```
found 71 vulnerabilities (36 low, 20 moderate, 14 high, 1 critical) in 11345 scanned packages
  71 vulnerabilities require semver-major dependency updates.
```

At the top of the audit:

> Run  `npm install react-scripts@2.1.2`  to resolve 71 vulnerabilities SEMVER WARNING: Recommended action is a potentially breaking change

After I do that `npm install react-scripts@2.1.2` the vulnerabilities are reduced to only 1:

```
                   === npm audit security report ===


                             Manual Review
         Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

      Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance


High            Missing Origin Validation

Package         webpack-dev-server

Patched in      >=3.1.11

Dependency of   react-scripts

Path            react-scripts > webpack-dev-server

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/725
```

After I do a `npm install webpack-dev-server@3.1.14`, I get 2 new issues:

```
                   === npm audit security report ===


                             Manual Review
         Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

      Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance


High            Missing Origin Validation

Package         webpack-dev-server

Patched in      >=3.1.11

Dependency of   react-scripts

Path            react-scripts > webpack-dev-server

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/725


High            Missing Origin Validation

Package         webpack-dev-server

Patched in      >=3.1.11

Dependency of   webpack-dev-server

Path            webpack-dev-server

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/725
```

That more info link suggests an update to version 3.1.6 or later. What I do is way higher than that ...

**Questions**

To have a better understanding of what `npm audit` does, I'd like to discuss the following remarks:

1. Why does doing `npm install webpack-dev-server@3.1.14` add an issue, rather than fix the one mentioned before? Looks like the previous issue remains even ...
2. Why does the vulnerabilities count drop from 356 to 71 after fixing only 3 issues while the total packages count is the same?
3. Why did the audit not suggest me to do `npm install webpack-dev-server@3.1.11` or higher if it knows the issue is patched since 3.1.11? it did know `npm install react-scripts@2.1.2` was necessary earlier.
4. What should I do to fix the issue mentioned in question #1?

PS: That [nodesecurity](https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/725) link suggests to update `webpack-dev-server` to version 3.1.6 or higher. I'm doing much higher than that ...

PPS: I tried `npm install webpack-dev-server@3.1.11` as well, no difference.

Comment: On point 2: There was a pretty popular npm package [(event-stream)](https://medium.com/intrinsic/compromised-npm-package-event-stream-d47d08605502) that was compromised recently that meant that a *lot* of older versions of popular packages were marked as vulnerabilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The advisory page for the `webpack-dev-server` vulnerability](https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/725/versions) listed the latest version as an affected version. This has been caused by a typo in the npm security repository, as reported in [a thread in the npm community forum.](https://npm.community/t/npm-audit-sweems-to-get-semver-wrong/4352) The typo has been fixed a few hours later.

Comment: Wow, looks to be a really old issue. Obviously it's not high on the to-fix radar, ie likely not going to be fixed soon. So why would the audit report mention it -is- patched?

Comment: @Spikee I have looked at the GitHub repository ([webpack/webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server)), and it references to a thread in the npm community forum. I have updated the answer to be accurate.

Comment: So basically it's a false negative if I'm at version 3.1.11 or higher?

Comment: @Spikee Looks like it is. [The issue was reported 2 days ago,](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1615) and the typo was discovered 4 hours ago, so it may take a while.

Comment: The typo has been finally fixed, the latest version is no longer in the advisory.